# How will an event without a year indicator be indexed?

Tags: splunk

I have a task to index a log file where timestamp looks like this: `Jan 13 03:43:31.662`, there is no year indication. I have no means of changing this, the application generating those logs does not permit it.

So, is Splunk able to append the current year?
Is there going to be a collision between the events in a year's time?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Splunk will use the current year if one is not specified.  Just put `TIME_FORMAT = %b %d %H:%M:%S.%3N` in your props.conf file.

There's no danger of collision.

Comment: Indeed, the year has been recognized correctly, will see in a year's time about the collision :)